# How to set string in the structure part of NRF24?

Tags: nrf24l01+

Can anyone help me on how to correct my program ? I want to transmit value in string form.

I put this to TX code

```
struct payload_t
{

 String sensor1;
};
```

..................

At the loop part I put this code

```
String sensor1 = (String(x) + "," + String(y) + "," + String(z)) ;
```

In the RX part I put this code

```
 struct payload_t
{

 String sensor1;
};
```

At the loop part

```
RF24NetworkHeader header;
payload_t payload;
network.read(header,&payload,sizeof(payload)); 

Serial.println("Sensor1 "); 

Serial.println(payload.sensor1);
```

Below is the Attach picture result of RX code.[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually 'instantiate' the struct in the TX and construct `sensor1` as `payload.sensor1 = ...`? Anyways, there's still a problem.

You are using `String` in your payload. The third argument to `read` is the maximum message length that can be stored in `payload`. In your `read` call, you passed the size of payload as `MAX_LEN`. You will receive incomplete payloads since the String object in the RX `payload` struct has no content in it yet and thus `payload`'s size, which you passed as `MAX_LEN`, will be less than that of the actual payload that was transmitted. Just ditch the Strings and try:

TX:

```
int vals = {x, y, z};   // guessing they are ints

network.write(header, &vals, sizeof(vals));
```

RX:

```
int vals[3];
network.read(header, &vals, sizeof(vals));

Serial.print(vals[0]); Serial.print(',');
Serial.print(vals[1]); Serial.print(',');
Serial.println(vals[2]);
```